# Append unique item to an array in ElasticSearch in Go

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, go

**UseCase**

- Add an object item in field of type array in elastic search
- If the field does not exist create one and add the item to the field
- If the field exists the item should only be added/append if the item is not present in the array i.e no duplicates in the array.

**Code**

```
func (elasticSearchClient *ElasticSearchClient) Upsert(index string, indextype string, id string, jobApplication models.JobApplication) {

client := elasticSearchClient.GetClient()
upsert, err := client.Update().
    Index(index).Type(indextype).Id(id).
    Script(elastic.NewScript("if(! ctx._source.jobApplications.contains(application)){ ctx._source.jobApplications += application }").
        Params(map[string]interface{}{"application": jobApplication})).
    Upsert(map[string]interface{}{"jobApplications": jobApplication}).
    Do()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error , got: %v", err.Error())
}

fmt.Println(upsert)
}
```

**Note**

- jobApplication is a struct type

**Error**:

> Error 400 (Bad Request): failed to execute script
>   [type=illegal_argument_exception]

Comment: In order to achieve what you want, you need a script like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303836/converting-elastic-search-field-to-array/33304787#33304787

Comment: Can you show the full error you get from your ES logs?